# Best practice about average time to accept an answer and accept answer decision

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, community, best-practices

What is the common sense for the time to accept a user answer?

For example, I usually think that I need to wait, for example, 1 week or more, because some questions have more than one answer and I like to hear different answers than accept the first one that appears. I want to read more answers about this subject.

Another point I want to discuss: is there a option where I can pass the decision for the community chooses what is the best answer in my questions?

Thank you!

Comment: From that Q&A, the recommendation is at least 24-48 hours, but no harm in waiting longer if there isn't a good answer, or moving more quickly if there's already an excellent answer that makes it seem unlikely a better one would come along. You can look at votes to estimate which answer the community thinks is best, but ultimately choosing the accepted answer is *for the question asker*.

Comment: @BryanKrause, thanks for your input! Yes, that question is a good enlightenment of a lot of doubts I had including the first point of this question. I agree with you that I can base my accept decision based in the vote of the users, that is very useful.

Comment: *where I can pass the decision for the community chooses what is the best answer in my questions?* We use up and down votes for that. Please remember that an accepted answer doesn't mean the "best" answer. It means: "this answer helped me most". We can't do telepathy into your head/mind to decide for you what helped you most. At worst you pick none. If that makes you unhappy role a fair dice. You can even accept the answer that was so wrong that made you finally saw the light. Unconventional but not forbidden.

Comment: Some things to be wary about by choosing based on votes, though, include things like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem - early answers tend to get more votes even if they aren't the best. So be careful when using that as a criteria and do think carefully about which answer is most helpful to you and best written. However if an answer gets a lot of downvotes, you might look carefully to see what might be wrong about it even if it initially seems correct.

Comment: @rene, your counterpoint is fair, an answer votes is a subjective matter, It does not defines the quality of the question, so the votes is a way to help the owner of the question to see which answers were more relevant than others but the final decision is from the owner of the question.